# Iterating through columns and subtracting with the Last Column in pd.dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am a python newbie and currently sitting on the evaluation of my simulations. I have read the results of the tab files into a pandas dataframe.
My index is the frequency. The remaining columns represent the amplitude of the calculated PSD.

I want to subtract these columns (e.g. a,b,c,d ...) with the last column, which is my test data.

The first table is an example of my current Dataframe. I want to substract each column/row with the test_data to get at the end the Standard deviation etc. of each column like in the following table:

| frequency (index) | A | B | C | test_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.2 | 5.0 | 2.4 | 1.9 |
| 2 | 2.1 | 3.0 | 2.7 | 2.6 |
| 3 | 3.0 | 6.0 | 2.9 | 2.8 |

The following table/dataframe is the wanted outcome after the loop.

| frequency (index) | A | B | C | test_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test_data[1]-A[1] | test_data[1]-B[1] | test_data[1]-C[1] | 1.9 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | .... |
| 3 | test_data[n]-A[n] | test_data[n]-B[n] | test_data[n]-C[n] | 2.8 |
| average of column | 0.33 | -2.3 | -0.233 |  |

| frequency (index) | A | B | C | test_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.7 | -3.1 | -0.5 | 1.9 |
| 2 | 0.5 | -0.4 | -0.1 | 2.6 |
| 3 | -0.2 | -3.2 | -0.1 | 2.8 |
| average of column | 0.33 | -2.3 | -0.233 |  |

I woult be very very grateful for any help regarding the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drop` to get rid of the non target columns, then `rsub` to subtract the test_data. Finally `concat` to the original dataset:

```
df2 = df.drop(columns=['frequency (index)', 'test_data']).rsub(df['test_data'] ,axis=0)

out = pd.concat([df.assign(**df2), df2.sum().to_frame().T])
```

Comment: This was'nt from me. Ill try your code :) Thx for the fast reply